# How does sites such as livescore.com work?

Tags: php

I had an idea to work on a livescore site with some additions, however before even trying to work on one, I would like to know from where such sites get their data from?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea for this particular site, but it seems like there are a couple of viable possibilities:

- Subscribe to a live feed of information from a provider, e.g. a broadcaster or similar. I would imagine this would cost a fair bit and be subject to restrictions on use, etc.
- Hire people to obtain the information from a variety of sources (including primary sources, i.e. watch several of the games) and update a database manually.
- Scrape ("borrow") the information from one or more other sites which do one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using google live sports data api xml ->http://www.xmlsportsfeeds.com/products/live-scores/ it's a kind of paid rss feeds and they can be quite expensive.